# .NET Framework Outputting to Console?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a TextWriter that outputs to a TextBox.
I've connected the TextWriter to Console.Out:

```
// set application console output to the output text box
Console.SetOut(TextWriter.Synchronized(new TextBoxWriter(this)));

class TextBoxWriter : TextWriter
{
  public override void WriteLine(string value)
  {
    // output to text box
  }
}
```

This works fine however I am finding that the .NET framework itself is writing trace/debug output to the console and therefore my window!

For example the user can click on a button which creates a control on a form. This will output something like:

```
170,130 0,0
```

The call stack shows that the textwriter WriteLine function is being called from external code in response to MyForm.Controls.Add(...);

If the user resizes the control then nonsense like the following is written by the .NET framework to the console:

```
0.574257425742574 @ 1
```

The call stack shows that the textwriter WriteLine function is being called from external code in response to MyControl.Width = NewValue;

This happens when my application is built for debug and release.

I do not turn on trace or debug functionality.

It happens even if DEBUG and TRACE are not defined.

My application  does not mention or do anything related to debug or trace.

I don't do anything else with the console.

My application doesn't call anything in System.Diagnostics.

Using C#, .NET 4.0, Windows 7 64-bit, Visual Studio 2010.

This is driving me crazy. Any suggestions on what to try next?

Comment: Somewhere in your program, you have Console.WriteLine(...) calls, right? Why don't you change those to use your TextBoxWriter directly? Or create your own indirection, different from Console.Out?

Comment: I'm using it to redirect IronPython print statements. I don't want to create a tight coupling between the single output window and the multiple python modules throughout my application.

Comment: Same question applies. Do you have control over the IronPython code? Can you replace the print statements by something else? Then again, you probably wouldn't be asking this question if you could...

Comment: Could you use a trace listener instead? If you can `Trace.WriteLine` in IronPython, you could use a trace listener that traces to your textbox.

Comment: I can see a workaround by wrapping the TextBoxWriter in an interface, passing it to the Python modules and using something like engine.Runtime.IO.SetOutput(stream, txtWriter); however I would prefer to understand and solve what is happening here with the strange console output.